# Why I can't deserialize std::array like this?

Tags: c++, initialization, aggregate, c++14, declaration

Why I can't deserialize std::array like this?

```
#include <array>

struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

int main()
{
   std::array<Point, 3> m_points { 
      { 1.0f, 1.0f }, 
      { 2.0f, 2.0f }, 
      { 3.0f, 3.0f }
   };
}
```

Doing this I get error:

> error: too many initializers for `std::array<Point, 3ul>`

but it works like this:

```
std::array<Point, 3> m_points { 
   Point{ 1.0f, 1.0f }, 
   Point{ 2.0f, 2.0f }, 
   Point{ 3.0f, 3.0f } 
};
```

In contrast `std::map` can be initialized with both ways written below:

```
   std::map<int, int> m1 {std::pair<int, int>{1,2}, std::pair<int, int>{3,4}}; 
   std::map<int, int> m2 {{1,2}, {3,4}};
```

Comment: Wrong number of braces? Try `std::array<Point, 3> m_points {{{ 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 2.0f, 2.0f }, { 3.0f, 3.0f }}};`. [Seems to work...](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/747be1b02cacb8e2)

Comment: I think the problem is that the compiler does not know what struct you want to initialize in the first example. Even though you're telling the array the type it can not see that you want `Point`

Comment: @meetaig looks like that to me too, but same kind of code works for `std::map`, you don't need to write `std::map<int, int> m {std::pair<int, int>{1,2}, std::pair<int, int>{3,4}};` instead you just can write `std::map<int, int> m {1,2}, 3,4}};` What is the difference?

Comment: I have never heard `desalinize` in this context before. I have inferred it to mean initialize?

Comment: What is the meaning of _desalinize_ in this context?

Comment: Well this is me just guessing, but map expects something like a `std::pair`, so maybe they built in something to automatically convert it when no further information is given? Whereas array can take any type so it would be difficult to make something this specialized for the implementation

Comment: @Narek, the c'tor type. `std::array`s are all implicitly declared. `std::map` has a c'tor taking an `std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this declaration and initialization

```
   std::array<Point, 3> m_points { 
      { 1.0f, 1.0f }, 
      { 2.0f, 2.0f }, 
      { 3.0f, 3.0f }
   };
```

the compiler considers the first initializer in braces like the initializer of the whole array (of the internal aggregate). `std::array` is an aggregate that contains another aggregate.

Write instead

```
   std::array<Point, 3> m_points {
      { 
      { 1.0f, 1.0f }, 
      { 2.0f, 2.0f }, 
      { 3.0f, 3.0f }
      }
   };
```

In the second case

```
std::array<Point, 3> m_points { 
   Point{ 1.0f, 1.0f }, 
   Point{ 2.0f, 2.0f }, 
   Point{ 3.0f, 3.0f } 
};
```

each initializer is considered sequentially as an initializer of a next element of the internal aggregate.

Consider this simple demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

struct array
{
    int a[10];
};

int main()
{
    array a = { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler issues an error like

```
prog.cpp:14:33: error: too many initializers for 'array'
  array a = { { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 } };
                                 ^
```

That is it decided that `{ 0, 0 }` is an initializer of the internal array (internal aggregate). Thus the next initializer in braces does not have a corresponding data member in the outer aggregate (structure).

Comment: I totally don't understand why adding two more curly braces solves the problem.

Comment: @Narek, because with the extra pair of curly braces (or `=`) you'd be doing aggregate initialization.

Comment: @StoryTeller Maybe and analogical example will clarify?

Comment: @Narek Usually std::array is defined like a structure containing an array. The first braces inside the outer braces is considered as an initializer of this array. When there are more than one braces then the compiler decides that there are more initializers than members of the aggregate.

Comment: Why I have to deal with the internal implementation of the `std::array`? I just want to initialize it and I don't care how it is designed.

Comment: @Narek, because the standard defined it to be a light holder of a bare array, thus able to be aggregate initialized. The dup linked above is quite descriptive about this.

Answer (score 3):

`std::array` has no explicitly defined constructors, unlike other standard containers such as `std::vector` or `std::map`, but only the automatically provided constructors. With `std::vector`, the compiler will try to match your expression against each available constructor and for a construct like

```
std::vecor<Point> m_points { {1.0f,1.0f}, {2.0f,2.0f}, {3.0f,3.0f} };
```

finds a match with the constructor

```
std::vector::vector(initializer_list<T>, const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

But with `std::array`, it must use aggregate initialisation of the underlying array (`Point[3]` in your case) and hence your construction does not match. To get it to work, you must add another pair of braces

```
std::array<Point, 3> m_points { 
  { { 1.0f, 1.0f },
    { 2.0f, 2.0f }, 
    { 3.0f, 3.0f } }
};
```

Comment: Why I have to deal with the internal implementation of the std::array? I just want to initialize it and I don't care how it is designed. Do you agree that this is shitty?

Comment: That's another, completely different question altogether. Don't expect answers to questions you didn't (initially) ask.

Comment: Neither in comments? :)